# Parse variable from URL to display different content on HTML page (JS)

Tags: javascript

I have an email newsletter being sent out each week with a different subject and there's one webpage where you can click to from the email.

On week 1 the email is about 'phones' and if someone clicked the link it could contain a slightly different variable (for example week 1 being ?content=phone on the end of the URL).

When the webpage loads, only the content on phones is displayed.

There is going to be 8 emails so there will be 8 sets of content and different variables in the URLs on each week.

I just need a javascript to do this?

Comment: why the double question?

Comment: @yoda I think I gave a bad explanation in the first case.

Comment: Can't you use server-side logic to handle that? Example:
<?php if($_GET['content'] == "phone") { echo "phone it is"; } else if...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this has to be done on a static page on client side, you could use `window.location.hash` to show/hide different parts of the page.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.location

Answer (score 0):

You can do something very simple and old-school with just HTML like:

```
<a name="phone"></a><h1>This is my phone section</h1>
<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
<a name="car"></a><h1>This is my car section</h1>
<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
<a name="house"></a><h1>This is my house section</h1>
<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
```

Then all of your urls look like:
emaillink1.html#car

Where the section you want at the top follows the hash mark.